# Few questions in ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, imageresizer

I am following the documentation [available here](http://imageresizing.net/docs/configuration-all) to resize images in our web sites
and have some questions.

1. clientcache - For testing purpose we used two days. However what could be the ideal value that I can use for production? What will happen if do not set clientcache minutes at all?
2. DefaultEndpointsProtocol for AzureReader2 connection string can be either http or https. what are the pros and cons of each? how do I decide that I have to go for http or https? All our sites are http and some are https, so which one can I choose for imageResizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On #1, you're asking 'How long should I set the Expires header for on my images`. [Google has a good intro to HTTP caching basics](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching).

On #2, you're asking what the merits of HTTPS over HTTP area, I [suggest the HTTPS Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).